# bias when all IV are constrained to have positive effects

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis

In a multivariate regression model $y \sim X$ we want to constrain for all $X$ (which are also positive) to have positive effects ($\beta > 0$), eg using half normal priors. Does this lead to a statistical bias, as the error might be more negative to counterbalance the positive bits? I guess true positive effects could be under-estimated.

Comment: Bayesian estimators are typically biased, and this situation is no exception.